# What path does B. Alan Wallace teach?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, vajrayana, stages-of-the-path, alan-wallace

I am long time student of Chogyam Trungpa. Unfortunately, the current situation at the sangha (now Shambhala International) is in a state of chaos. I am interested in becoming B. Alan Wallace's student. I'm wondering if his path is similar to Vajradhatu, in other words, start with shamatha/vipassana, then ngondro, and then abhiseka. Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism Q&A. Are you familiar with Reginald A. Ray https://www.dharmaocean.org/ - he is a prominent student of C.T. who spun off his own practice. Might be another option to consider?

Comment: i hadn't heard about that, hope you're OK. hopefully Chogyam Trungpa was just abusing his power over his students, and that's all he did. good luck in finding a new teacher!

Comment: @Andrei Volkov, I have thought of Reginald Ray but he is on retreat and not taking any more students. Word is that Ray's ego is gotten a little out of control; on a bit of a Guru trip. From what I've read Alan Wallace is probably a good bet.

Comment: As a C.T. student are you not worried that A.W. seems to be more inclined towards theory and formal structured "buddhism" rather than hard-core real-life practice?

Comment: Not true at all about Alan Wallace. He's all about practice. Checkout this link: http://media.sbinstitute.com/courses/fall2012/01-settling-body-speech-and-mind-in-its-natural-state/